# restart python app on openshift doesn't reload environment variables

Tags: django, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying reload my application on Openshift and having some problems.
Don't matter if run `rhc app restart` or `rhc app reload` to restart/reload the application, my environment variables aren't reloaded.

Then, to solve the problem, I'm forced to stop and start the application.

PS:
Cartridge: python-2.7
Framework: Django

Comment: I think there is something funky going in general with at least the openshift python servers since last week. Read thru the first and seconds pages here op stack overflow. Openshift support has not responded on anything :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to do:

```
$ rhc app stop -a appname
$ rhc app start -a appname
```

instead of restart or reload.

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1104955#c15

Comment: solved for php as well :D cheers, thanks mate for simple solution, i was worried :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the environment variables via the rhc env set command? Or using action hooks? I suggest using the rhc env set command, as they will persist correctly between restarts etc.

Comment: I'm using `rhc env`. Thank!