# Running Django 1.8 on OpenShift scalable app

Tags: django, openshift

I am having problems running Django(1.8.7) app on scalable OpenShift platform using python 2.7. For some reason it can not get info of enviroment variable `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL`. Well this is the error:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=69306): Target WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/5d5/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=69306): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/5d5/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application", line 21, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup()
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/var/lib/openshift/5d5/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/bet/controller/settings.py", line 59, in <module>
     url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL'))
   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 143, in urlparse
     tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 182, in urlsplit
     i = url.find(':')
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This is how I used that variable in settings.py that worked before:

```
import urlparse
DATABASES = {}
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL'))

    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'],
        'USER': url.username,
        'PASSWORD': url.password,
        'HOST': url.hostname,
        'PORT': url.port,
        }
```

and this is my `application` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'bet'))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'controller.settings'
virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except:
    pass

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If I login to my app through `rhc ssh bet` and try to print variable, it works ok:

```
echo $OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL
postgresql://admin:password-mynick.rhcloud.com:port/
```

And idea what am I missing. I look [here](https://github.com/Gpzim98/Django-OpenShift-1.8) with no luck.

NOTE: My app is named `bet`. But since I am moving it to scalable app, I created `abet` app in openshift. I kept name of app as `bet` in `wsgi` folder. Might this cause some problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like some kind of [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1104955#c15) in [OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438662/restart-python-app-on-openshift-doesnt-reload-environment-variables). I tried to restart/reload app, no luck.

```
$ rhc app stop -a appname
$ rhc app start -a appname
```

Stopping and starting app made it work. (Reloaded environment variables)

Answer (score 0):

Use this link

[OpenShift Community](https://developers.openshift.com/en/contact.html)

and be patient, they will contact and will assist you.

Don't forgot to check openshift log folder

```
$ rhc ssh app-name

$ cd $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR
```

check the log files inside that folder, then may provide some useful information to your problem and you can describe it better to support  team.