# Openshift - Scaling app does not start

Tags: node.js, git, openshift, haproxy

I'm using Openshift with nodejs. When I use a single gear, no issue to get my app working but when I use a scaling app, even if the git push command says 'success', the app returns a 503 error.

When I execute rhc tail , my first log output is correctly written. 
Do you know how can I figure out what happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to stop and start OpenShift app. Sometimes you need to restart app to load all dependencies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890241/running-django-1-8-on-openshift-scalable-app

Comment: Thanks. In fact, a followed that one: https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-host-your-java-ee-application-with-auto-scaling/  and it worked. Just a ping error.